# VBScript to get the Computername and split the Computename

Tags: vbscript

I'm very new to VBScript, looking for a script to get the computername and split the computername into two sets one with first three letters of computername and the next with forth and fifth letter in the computername. Eg. ***Computername*** splitted into ***Comp*** and ***ut***.

please help.

Comment: Does [this page](http://www.ezineasp.net/Samples/Classic-ASP/VbScript-String-Functions/String-Mid-Function/Default.aspx) help? I found it by searching on Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Left() resp. Mid() - and reflect on your counting:

```
>> s = "ComputerName"
>> WScript.Echo Left(s, 3)
>> WScript.Echo Left(s, 4)
>> WScript.Echo Mid(s, 4, 2)
>> WScript.Echo Mid(s, 5, 2)
>>
Com
Comp
pu
ut
```

Use WScript.Network to get the data:

```
>> WScript.Echo CreateObject("WScript.Network").Computername
```